# Problem with NTFRS - Missing Sysvol and Netlogon on a 2003 Server

Tags: active-directory

This is a problem that is affecting me. Although this description wasn´t written by me (seen at www.experts-exchange.com (1), one of the kind of sites stackoverflow was created because of) it applies 95% to the problem I´m having. Next time I won´t follow MS advice, The domain was working until I tried the suggested solution on the event log ("Enable Journal Wrap Automatic Restore"). What a mistake it was!!!.

Description (as seen in (1)) follows:

(1)
http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft%5fOperating%5fSystems/Server/Windows%5f2003%5fActive%5fDirectory/Q%5f22871376.html

---------- Cut starts here ----------

I am having some apparently serious problems with a 2003 SBS server.

We have just started the process of putting in a second Domain Controller into this network for a project.

I performed the same task in a lab environment before I started on the live environment, and had no problems.

Firstly, we upgraded the SBS (tisserver) to 2003 R2. After that, I did the adprep to update the schema to R2.

I built up the 2003 R2 server (tisdr), installed DNS, joined it to the domain and did a DCPROMO.

This all worked fine, but I discovered errors in the File Replicaction Service event log on the new server:

---

Event ID 13508 - Source NtFRS

---

The File Replication Service is having trouble enabling replication from tisserver.TIS.local to TISDR for c:\windows\sysvol\domain using the DNS name tisserver.TIS.local. FRS will keep retrying.
 Following are some of the reasons you would see this warning.

[1] FRS can not correctly resolve the DNS name tisserver.TIS.local from this computer.
 [2] FRS is not running on tisserver.TIS.local.
 [3] The topology information in the Active Directory for this replica has not yet replicated to all the Domain Controllers.

This event log message will appear once per connection, After the problem is fixed you will see another event log message indicating that the connection has been established.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

---

When I went and checked the SBS, I found the following error had been occurring:

---

Eventid ID 13568 - Source NtFrs

---

The File Replication Service has detected that the replica set "DOMAIN SYSTEM VOLUME (SYSVOL SHARE)" is in JRNL_WRAP_ERROR.

Replica set name is    : "DOMAIN SYSTEM VOLUME (SYSVOL SHARE)"
 Replica root path is   : "c:\windows\sysvol\domain"
 Replica root volume is : "\.\C:"
 A Replica set hits JRNL_WRAP_ERROR when the record that it is trying to read from the NTFS USN journal is not found.  This can occur because of one of the following reasons.

[1] Volume "\.\C:" has been formatted.
 [2] The NTFS USN journal on volume "\.\C:" has been deleted.
 [3] The NTFS USN journal on volume "\.\C:" has been truncated. Chkdsk can truncate the journal if it finds corrupt entries at the end of the journal.
 [4] File Replication Service was not running on this computer for a long time.
 [5] File Replication Service could not keep up with the rate of Disk IO activity on "\.\C:".
 Setting the "Enable Journal Wrap Automatic Restore" registry parameter to 1 will cause the following recovery steps to be taken to automatically recover from this error state.
 [1] At the first poll, which will occur in 5 minutes, this computer will be deleted from the replica set. If you do not want to wait 5 minutes, then run "net stop ntfrs" followed by "net start ntfrs" to restart the File Replication Service.
 [2] At the poll following the deletion this computer will be re-added to the replica set. The re-addition will trigger a full tree sync for the replica set.

WARNING: During the recovery process data in the replica tree may be unavailable. You should reset the registry parameter described above to 0 to prevent automatic recovery from making the data unexpectedly unavailable if this error condition occurs again.

To change this registry parameter, run regedit.

Click on Start, Run and type regedit.

Expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
Click down the key path:
   "System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NtFrs\Parameters"
Double click on the value name
   "Enable Journal Wrap Automatic Restore"
and update the value.

If the value name is not present you may add it with the New->DWORD Value function under the Edit Menu item. Type the value name exactly as shown above.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

---

After doing a bit of reading, it seemed like the right thing to do was a non-authoritative resotre, so I went through and created the registry key, then stopped and started the NTFRS service.

As expected, I got:

---

EventID 13560 - Source NtFRS

---

The File Replication Service is deleting this computer from the replica set "DOMAIN SYSTEM VOLUME (SYSVOL SHARE)" as an attempt to recover from the error state,
 Error status = FrsErrorSuccess
 At the next poll, which will occur in 5 minutes, this computer will be re-added to the replica set. The re-addition will trigger a full tree sync for the replica set.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

---

Exactly five minutes later, I got:

---

EventID 13520 - Source NtFRS

---

The File Replication Service moved the preexisting files in c:\windows\sysvol\domain to c:\windows\sysvol\domain\NtFrs_PreExisting___See_EventLog.

The File Replication Service may delete the files in c:\windows\sysvol\domain\NtFrs_PreExisting___See_EventLog at any time. Files can be saved from deletion by copying them out of c:\windows\sysvol\domain\NtFrs_PreExisting___See_EventLog. Copying the files into c:\windows\sysvol\domain may lead to name conflicts if the files already exist on some other replicating partner.

In some cases, the File Replication Service may copy a file from c:\windows\sysvol\domain\NtFrs_PreExisting___See_EventLog into c:\windows\sysvol\domain instead of replicating the file from some other replicating partner.

Space can be recovered at any time by deleting the files in c:\windows\sysvol\domain\NtFrs_PreExisting___See_EventLog.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at

---

&

---

EventID 13553 - Source NtFRS

---

The File Replication Service successfully added this computer to the following replica set:
    "DOMAIN SYSTEM VOLUME (SYSVOL SHARE)"

Information related to this event is shown below:
Computer DNS name is "tisserver.TIS.local"
Replica set member name is "TISSERVER"
Replica set root path is "c:\windows\sysvol\domain"
Replica staging directory path is "c:\windows\sysvol\staging\domain"
Replica working directory path is "c:\windows\ntfrs\jet"

For more information, see Help and Support Center at

---

---------- Cut ends here ----------

From this point on the responses I got start to drift from the original poster:

---

EventID 13566 - Source NtFRS

---

File Replication Service is scanning the data in the system volume. Computer DOMSERVER cannot become a domain controller until this process is complete. The system volume will then be shared as SYSVOL.

To check for the SYSVOL share, at the command prompt, type: 
net share

When File Replication Service completes the scanning process, the SYSVOL share will appear.

The initialization of the system volume can take some time. The time is dependent on the amount of data in the system volume.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

---

I have left it for about an hour and a half now, and am not seeing any sign of a sysvol or netlogon share yet. The users are unable to log on. I don´t know where to go to from here. I´m in such desperate state that, if I had the money, I sure would pay experts-exchange (and the bad guys would win, I know :( ). Unfortunaly, I can´t do that for many reasons (not having a credit card is one of them).

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: sorry for my not so good english. It´s not my mother tongue. Next time I will be better at it. :)

Answer (score 3):

"Using the BurFlags registry key to reinitialize File Replication Service replica sets" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290762) did the trick!!!! Yessss!!! ufff!!! I feel like flying right now!!!

Comment: I wish I found this post before spending 12 hours on figuring out why AD DS died. Took two seconds to bring it back with this